# Updated to JDK7 on the Mac and now getting AquaTableUI exception

Tags: macos, java, osx-mountain-lion, java-7

Basically I'm getting an exception of the type:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apple/laf/AquaTableUI

On the Mac OS X 10.8.2 (latest Mac OS) with JDK7. No idea what is causing it. And yes the application is signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because one of the libraries was referencing JDK6 specific libraries that were no longer supported on JDK7. I had to upgrade the jar from those libraries when they became available.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you have to use the problem is that you are using Oracle JDK. It is known to have pure Mac OS X support. Most probably your problem have to be resolved by switching back to Apple JDK 6.

I realize that you can manually add JAR file with AquaUI to your classpath. But when I tested this approach I found many un-obvious bugs, for sample this one: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7166379

Such a bugs could show you gray screen of death. They could also be a security holes that will allow trojans to occupy your mac. You can google "Flashback trojan java mac" for details.

On these reasons I hardly recommend to use Apple's JDK.

Comment: Reverting back to an older JVM is not really a good solution because that means you'll never be able to upgrade ;)